# Laravel user_id not being referenced as foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create address creation for profiles in my project.
A user has many addresses.

User model

```
public function addresses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

Address model

```
class Address extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['region', 'city', 'address', 'postal_code', 'user_id'];


    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Address store function

```
public function store(Request $request){
        return Address::create($request->all());
    }
```

Address table

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('region')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

when I try to store details into an address, the user_id is not being referenced, so its not being connected to the user that is storing the details.

i keep getting

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `addresses` (`region`, `city`, `address`, `postal_code`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (12, 123, 1234, 1111, 2024-02-12 03:15:38, 2024-02-12 03:15:38))",
```

I made it nullable but the problem with it is that it's not being stored to a specific user's data

Comment: Welcome to SO ... we have no idea what input is being passed with the Request ... it would seem `user_id` is not being passed at all

Comment: how do i make it so that whenever a user sends a request to create an address, the address table takes the user's id and sets it as a foreign key. so that the address data is tied to only the user that sent the request?

Answer (score 1):

> how do i make it so that whenever a user sends a request to create an address, the address table takes the user's id and sets it as a foreign key. so that the address data is tied to only the user that sent the request?

You could use the relationship for the user:

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    return $request
        ->user()
        ->addresses()
        ->create(
            $request->all()
        );
}
```

That way you could also avoid having `user_id` as a part of your `Address` model's property for fillable fields.